# add class to paragraph javascript only

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a class to a paragraph with javascript. but it ends only passing the class to wrong id. I would like to change changes on the   `<p id="para" class="para" >NAV One</p>`
but at the moment it only changes the background of the list.
Any ideas ?

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var thelist = document.getElementsByClassName("alist");
    var para = document.getElementsByClassName("para");
    for (var i = 0; i < thelist.length; i++) {
        thelist[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var para = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    } else { 
        para.className += " " + 'active';
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

JSfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/FqqhY/4/

Comment: you are defining `para` twice, a heads up on that

Comment: The id of your `<p>` is not "list1"; that's the id you pass in the call to "toggle_visibility".

Comment: @Pointy yes thats one of the problem, if I change the para to list1. then the list actually stops working but the bg changes

Comment: The first time you fetch the "para" class elements, you don't do anything with the value of "para".  Then you overwrite "para" with the same element you fetched for "e".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want your toggle function to look more like this

```
function toggle_visibility(hyp, id) {

    // hide all lists
    var allLists = document.getElementsByClassName('alist');
    for (var i = 0; i < allLists.length; i++)
        allLists[i].style.display = 'none';

    // deactive all paragraphs
    var allParas = document.getElementsByClassName('para');
    for (var i = 0; i < allParas.length; i++)
        allParas[i].className = 'para';

    // select the clicked hyper link and its child paragraph
    var list = document.getElementById(id),
        para = hyp.getElementsByClassName('para')[0];

    // activate the current para and show the list
    para.className = 'para active';
    list.style.display = 'block';
}
```

You also need to pass `this` in as the first argument to the toggle function along with the corresponding list id

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(this, 'list1');">
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/VU8er/)

Comment: Yes Chris. exactly :)
Thank you mr.